# Biggest digit of number with recursive function

Tags: java

I have a Java function I want to convert to a recursive function without using Math.max().

```
static int biggest (int n)
{
  int result = 0;
  int i = n;

  while (i > 0)
  {
    if(i % 10 > result) result = i % 10;
    i = i / 10;
  }

  return result;
}
```

I have tried almost every thing I had in mind but I don't get the correct method.

Comment: Can you post the recursive version of the method, and tell us what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this,

```
static int biggest(int n) {
    int n1 = n%10;
    int n2 = n/10;

    if (n2 == 0) { // base case
        return n1;
    }
    int n3 = biggest(n2); // recurse here
    return n1 > n3 ? n1 : n3; // return the max
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your homework asignment was to implement this algorithm as a recursive function, you need to remove the loop and replace it with a recursive call.

What you want to do is look at the last digit of the input and see if it is larger than the largest digit in the number ou get when you divide the input with 10.

Answer (score 2):

Think in lines of:

> biggist n = current digit n > biggest leftover digits n ? current : leftovers

Answer (score 0):

Something along the following lines should work:

```
static int biggest(int n) {
    if (n < 10)  // base case: single digit
        return n;
    int digit = i % 10;  // last digit
    int digitRest = biggest(i / 10);  // recursive call
    if (digit > digitRest)
        return digit;
    else
        return digitRest;
}
```